# React - Inline CSS and Image won't load

Tags: reactjs

I'm still new to React and after I finished the tutorial I wanted to create something myself.

I've passed the url to make a `backgroundImage` style and add borders to try it out. Unfortunately I can see the img being set in the css but it won't actually display as expected.

As a test I also tried a simple `img` with `src` attribute set to my image and nothing would display.

I made a folder called img inside the src

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Home/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Portfolio(props) {
  const stylee = {
    backgroundImage:'url('+props.imgURL+')',
    borderWidth: 1,

  };
  const ide = 'portfolio'+props.counting;

  return (<div id={ide} style={stylee} className='portfolio'/>)
}


class Home extends Component {

  renderPortfolio(count,img){
    return <Portfolio counting={count} imgURL={img}/>
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      {this.renderPortfolio(1,'./img/1.jpeg')}
      {this.renderPortfolio(2,'./img/2.jpeg')}
      {this.renderPortfolio(3,'./img/1.jpeg')}
      <img src='./img/1.jpeg'/>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong that is preventing the images from displaying ?

edit-- I've changed my code to the working solution
Instead of passing the local img url, I used require() first then pass the image to props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Home/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Portfolio(props) {

  const counter = 'portfolio'+props.counting;

  const loadGambar = props.gmbr;
 // const loadGambar2 = require(props.gmbr);

  const stylee = {
    borderColor:props.color,
    border:1,
    borderWidth: 10,
    backgroundImage: "url("+loadGambar+")",
  }

  return(
    <div id={counter} className='portfolio' style={stylee}>
    </div>
  )
}

class Home extends Component {

  renderPortfolio(count,gambare){
    return <Portfolio counting={count} gmbr={gambare}/>
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div>
      {this.renderPortfolio(1,require('./img/1.jpg))}
      {this.renderPortfolio(2,require('./img/1.jpg'))}
      {this.renderPortfolio(3,require('./img/2.jpg'))}
      </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a working example based on your code: [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/q3xq29lzqw).

The problem with setting a background image is that it adapts to the dimensions of the `div`. In your case your `div` is empty in `Portfolio` so its dimensions are `0x0` and the image won't show. You will see from the link that I update the style and everything shows. Now the only issue you might have is that you don't have an image loader in your webpack configuration, if you are starting with react I would recommend `create-react-app`.

Comment: Hi, I ve updated my code and turns out my problem is that I cant load Image from local files only, online files work fine. As for localfiles, I've tried with `<img src=require(./img/1.jpg) />` and it works, but I cant seems to use `require(props.imgURL)`

Comment: I didn't configure any webpack, I think it is because I'm using create-react-app. but don't worry I have figured it out, `{this.renderPortfolio(1,require('./img/1.jpg))}` instead of passing it as url in the first place, I require my local image first so then I pass the image to props. Thank you !

Comment: Sure but that's not convenient, you should be able to import the image as you do with any other `.js` file and then use it across your whole component. The other way you have to do `require` every time while you could use a more intuitive alias in your `.js` file.